# Error updating database

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to update database from FreeTextBox in my web page. But I can't do this, my code is below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string page1 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
        "Data Source=NODE5-PC;Initial Catalog=hans;User ID=sa;Password=123");

    con.Open();

    string sql = "UPDATE PageMaster SET Content=@FreeText WHERE Page=@Page1 ";

    SqlCommand ucmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    ucmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FreeText", FreeText.Text);

    ucmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    FreeText.Text = "";
}
```

The error that occurs is:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Page1".

Comment: Sounds pretty clear... You haven't declared the scalar variable `@Page1`.

Answer (score 4):

The exception makes it clear, "...Must declare the scalar variable "@Page1"."

Try adding:

```
ucmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page1", <YOUR VALUE FOR @Page1>);
```